# Differential geometry and transition maps as communative diagrams

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the picture below.
[image]

I know pictures are usually looked down upon on this site but I have no experience with TikZ.

Anyway, I am learning about regular surfaces and transition maps in differential geometry. We have some regular surface $S$ and open sets $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{\tilde{U}}.$

Right now, I am trying to make a communative diagram with all of these maps to understand this better. But, I have never made a communative diagram in my life. Is anyone able to help me? And, is this information enough?

Comment: "communative"  ought  to be  commutative

Comment: You have indeed drawn the commutative triangle. You can do another one by taking derivatives and get the tangent plane of $S$ at $p$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you mind writing it out in the answer? I can give you a check for it.

Comment: You have drawn the very commutative triangle you're looking for. Is the question about having it made in tikzcd?

Comment: @cocompletehippopotamus How do I connect the top two? So it’s not a “square” here it’s only a triangle?

Comment: @cocompletehippopotamus and how can I do the derivative one like in a comment?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Commutative diagrams don't need to be squares, they can also be triangles. If you're looking to have it made in tikzcd, try out this online editor https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/ .